passport serialize/deserialize user google login problem
why if a user logged in with google makes a post to secrets the req.user only includes the googleId but when its a normal user it contains all the object stored in the db im trying to use the objectId that all elements are suppposed to have and i cant get it in the req.user only when its not a google logged in user how can i fix this ?

const usersSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    password:String,
    googleId:String,
    secret:String
});
usersSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User=mongoose.model("User", usersSchema)
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id.toString());
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(id);
      done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err, null);
    }
  });
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
      scope:["profile", "email"]
      
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            
            User.findOne({googleId:profile["id"]}).then(user=>{
                if (!user){
                    const newUser=new User({
                        email:profile.emails[0].value,
                        googleId:profile.id
                    })
                    newUser.save().then(resolve=>{return done(null, newUser);}).catch(error=>{console.log(error)})
                    
                }
                else{
                    return done(null, profile)
                }

            }).catch(error=>{return done(error)})
      
    }
  ));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("home");
});
app.get("/auth/google", 
    passport.authenticate("google", {scope:["profile", "email"]}));
app.get("/auth/google/secrets", 
    passport.authenticate("google", {failureRedirect:"/login"}),
    (req, res)=>{res.redirect("/secrets")}
);
app.get("/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login");
});
app.get("/register", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("register");
});
app.get("/secrets", (req, res)=>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){res.render("secrets")}
    else{res.redirect("/login")}
})
app.get("/logout", (req, res)=>{
    req.logout((err)=>{
        if (err){console.log(err)}
        else{res.redirect("/")}
    })
})
app.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    User.register({username:req.body.username}, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
        if (err){console.log(err);res.redirect("/register");}
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            })
        }
    });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
    const newUser=new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    req.login(newUser, (err)=>{
        if (err){console.log(err)}
        else{
            User.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{res.redirect("/secrets")})
        }
    })
})
app.get("/submit", (req, res)=>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){res.render("submit")}
    else{res.redirect("/login")}
});
app.post("/submit", (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.user);
    User.findOne({googleId:req.user.id}).then(user=>{
        User.updateOne({googleId:req.user.id}, {secret:req.body.secret}).then(resolve=>{res.redirect("/secrets")}).catch(error=>{console.log(error)});

    }).catch(error=>{console.log(error)});
})
app.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log("Server running on port 3000")});

